# React-bootstrap (BS v3) - can not use a ref from an input

Tags: react-bootstrap

I’m using react-bootstrap, but with bootstrap v3, because that’s the bootstrap version my project currently uses.

Now, I just need to have a *ref* from an *input*. In the react-bootstrap docs, it says you should use formControl’s *inputRef* property like this:

```
<FormControl inputRef={ref => { this.input = ref; }} />
```

But currently, I’m using a function and react hooks to build my component, instead of classes.
So I just wrote my code this way:

```
let inputReferencia = useRef(null);
```

In *onFocus* event, I use this statement to select the content of the input:

```
inputReferencia.current.select();
```

And, finally, this is my input, as per react-bootstrap syntax:

```
<FormGroup>
    <FieldGroup
        id="referencia"
        name="referencia"
        value={formValues.referencia}
        type="text"
        label="Referencia" 
        onFocus={(e) => onDescripcionReferenciaInputFocus(e)}
        onChange={(e) => onInputChange(e)} 
        inputRef={ref => { inputReferencia = ref; }} />
</FormGroup>
```

As React-bootstrap suggests, this is *FieldGroup*:

```
const FieldGroup = ({ id, label, help, ...props }) => {
    return (
        <FormGroup controlId={id} bsSize="small">
            <ControlLabel>{label}</ControlLabel>
            <FormControl {...props} />
            {help && <HelpBlock>{help}</HelpBlock>}
        </FormGroup>
    );
}
```

But when I try to access the *ref*, as in

```
inputReferencia.current.select()
```

the *current* property is undefined.
Of course, if I check out the ref in Chrome debugger, it was definitely initialized with something:

[image: react's ref in chrome debugger]

Can somebody help me to solve this issue?

Many thanks for your help …

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/forms/#form-control-props) you ought to use `ref` instead of `inputRef`. This is regardless of whether you are using `Bootstrap V3` or `Bootstrap V4` or any other version as React-bootstrap only uses their stylesheet.

In dealing with functional components and trying to access the child element's `ref` on the parent when the `ref` variable is declared on the parent, you can opt to use [`forwardRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html)

```
function App() {
  let inputReferencia = useRef(null);

  function onDescripcionReferenciaInputFocus(e) {
    console.log(`inputReferencia`, inputReferencia);
  }

  return (
    <Container>
      <FormGroup>
        <FieldGroup
          id="referencia"
          name="referencia"
          value={formValues.referencia}
          type="text"
          label="Referencia"
          onFocus={(e) => onDescripcionReferenciaInputFocus(e)}
          onChange={(e) => onInputChange(e)}
          ref={inputReferencia}
        />
      </FormGroup>
    </Container>
  );
}

const FieldGroup = React.forwardRef(({ id, label, help, ...props }, ref) => {
  return (
    <FormGroup controlId={id} bsSize="small">
      <ControlLabel>{label}</ControlLabel>
      <FormControl {...props} ref={ref} />
      {help && <HelpBlock>{help}</HelpBlock>}
    </FormGroup>
  );
});
```

[image: Edit lively-leaf-h1f1h]

Comment: Hi and many thanks for your answer. 
I still can't find a way to select the value on the control. I looked into the _ref.current_ that is provided from your solution, but I am still not able to find a select() method to select the possible value on the control. 
For example, in your codesandbox: if you type 5000; go out and then return back to the input … how can I use select() on the Input (via the _ref.current_) to select those 5000??? 
Well, hope you can help me further to find that answer. I am still very confused with this issue. 
Many thanks and bye …

Comment: Late reply, but just use `inputReferencia.current.select();`. I've updated my CodeSandBox

Comment: Hi, I can see this is working really well. If you run the mini app on CodeSandbox you can see that, after typing some text, it is selected when you tab back to it. Excellent ... many thanks ...